# Why doesn't changes appear for other users?

Tags: 2010, site

Whenever I change something on a SharePoint site, no one more than I can see that change. When I log in with another user, the things i changed on the site does not apply for them. I always make sure that I press save when a change has been made.

What is causing this?

Note that this only happens when I try to edit a site. Editing a list or an item in a list is not an isssue.

Edit: In the top of the web page it say: "Status: Check in but being edited and check out exclusively to [Insert name here]"

Comment: did you publish also?

Comment: @VarunVerma, that seems to be spot-on the solution!

Comment: @RobertLindgren :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please publish the page. On left side of the top ribbon you will see the button.

You can visit [this](http://mscerts.programming4.us/sharepoint/sharepoint%202010%20%20%20publish%20a%20page.aspx) link for details

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves you query.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I found out that I do not have the right permission to publish sites.